# Python screen share

Tags: python, sockets, screensharing, python-mss

Hi Im trying to build an application in python 3 for screen sharing and I looked in other codes  from the internet (some of them from StackOverFlow) and all of them just rapidly open up screenshots of my screen without capturing them into one screen , so its impossible to work with

i cant work with a screen sharing that pops up 100 tabs of screenshot every few seconds ( i dont think this is how its supposed to work)

I would like to capture them into one screen so i can work with it
and also that it wont make  my screen so messy with one hundred open tabs of screenshots that i cant handle

I would love for some help or technical advice

here is the code i found From stack over flow:

**Client.py**

```
from socket import socket
from zlib import decompress

import pygame

WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000


def recvall(conn, length):
    """ Retreive all pixels. """

    buf = b''
    while len(buf) < length:
        data = conn.recv(length - len(buf))
        if not data:
            return data
        buf += data
    return buf


def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5001):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    watching = True

    sock = socket()
    sock.connect((host, port))
    try:
        while watching:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    watching = False
                    break

            # Retreive the size of the pixels length, the pixels length and pixels
            size_len = int.from_bytes(sock.recv(1), byteorder='big')
            size = int.from_bytes(sock.recv(size_len), byteorder='big')
            pixels = decompress(recvall(sock, size))

            # Create the Surface from raw pixels
            img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), 'RGB')

            # Display the picture
            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Server.py**

```
from socket import socket
from threading import Thread
from zlib import compress

from mss import mss


WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000


def retreive_screenshot(conn):
    with mss() as sct:
        # The region to capture
        rect = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': WIDTH, 'height': HEIGHT}

        while 'recording':
            # Capture the screen
            img = sct.grab(rect)
            # Tweak the compression level here (0-9)
            pixels = compress(img.rgb, 6)

            # Send the size of the pixels length
            size = len(pixels)
            size_len = (size.bit_length() + 7) // 8
            conn.send(bytes([size_len]))

            # Send the actual pixels length
            size_bytes = size.to_bytes(size_len, 'big')
            conn.send(size_bytes)

            # Send pixels
            conn.sendall(pixels)


def main():
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5001))
    try:
        sock.listen(5)
        print('Server started.')

        while 'connected':
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Client connected IP:', addr)
            thread = Thread(target=retreive_screenshot, args=(conn,))
            thread.start()
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

p.s
 maybe it opens up so many tabs because im using it on my computer  - and it supposed to work between two computers. i do not know , would love for some help

A link the the original code's page:
[screen sharing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950962/screen-sharing-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It's not opening tab it is just showing your screen inside screen... For share between two pc all you need to add host machine/computer IPv4 Address for example:
in your server and client code. Which you will get by typing `ipconfig` \ `ifconfig` in your terminal/cmd:

your server code:

server.py

```
#---code
def main():
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind(('192.168.0.xxx',5001))
#----code
```

client.py

```
#---code
def main(host='192.168.0.xxx',port=5001):
#---code
```