# how to capture the mouse pointer in screenshot

Tags: python-mss

I use the python-mss to capture the screenshot and use these screenshot with opencv to generate a video recording. As I want to capture the mouse movement in the video.
But it seems that the mouse pointer can not be captured in snapshot. How can I capture the mouse pointer with python-mss?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opened issue for that: [#55](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/55). You can find some clues in the comments.

**Edit** 2023-04-09: as of MSS 8.0.0, it's possible to capture the cursor on GNU/Linux ([doc](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/search.html?q=cursor&check_keywords=yes&area=default)).

Answer (score 0):

At least under linux, here's a snippet that does it:

```
    with mss(with_cursor=True) as sct:
        # The region to capture
        rect = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1280, 'height': 1024}

        # Capture the screen
        img = sct.grab(rect)
```

This is a snippet adapted from here:
[Screen sharing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950962/screen-sharing-in-python)
for use in my application for use to drive a teleprompter screen:
https://github.com/poleguy/sweep/blob/master/screen_send.py

The 'clues' in the link mentioned by Tiger-222 provided the answer.